# is there a preprocessor macro to incorporate the build time?

Tags: gcc, preprocessor

GCC has

```
__TIMESTAMP__
This macro expands to a string constant that describes the date and time of the last modification of the current source file
```

But if that file does not get modified, the timestamp string doesn't change.

Is there a way to get a string indicating the time at compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `-D` flag from the command line:

```
gcc -DCOMPILE_TIME="\"$(date)\"" -c file.c
```

But if you use any popular build system, `file.c` won't get rebuilt unless it changes anyway, so it's not that different from `__TIMESTAMP__`.

Comment: Thank you.   If I set up one target with no dependencies, it should get compiled every time, yes?